# Call android runOnUiThread from cocos2dx may make the menutitem blink

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have recently been playing with cocos2dx and sometimes I need to call the java code to do some Android specific job. So I add a static method in the Java code and in the method I call runOnUiThread to do the job. And C++ calls the static java method.

It indeed works fine, except that SOMETIMES the call would make the menuItem which triggers the call blink, while at other times, it looks perfect.

I have a share function and the code looks like below, the share buttom (menu item) would sometimes blink after I click it. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

I remember seeing the similar problem somewhere, but just could not Google it out today...

Java

```
...
public static void onShare(final int mode, final int score) {
    ((AppActivity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        if(mode == 0) {
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ((AppActivity)mContext).getResources().getString(R.string.share_content0, score));
        }
        else {
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ((AppActivity)mContext).getResources().getString(R.string.share_content1, score));
        }
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        ((AppActivity)mContext).startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ((AppActivity)mContext).getResources().getString(R.string.send_to)));
    }
    });
}
...
```

C++, platform.cpp

```
...
void doShare(int mode, int score) {
    JniMethodInfo t;
    if( JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t,APPACTIVITY,
        "onShare", "(II)V")) {
        t.env->CallStaticIntMethod(t.classID, t.methodID, mode, score);
    }
}
...
```

C++, HelloScene.cpp

```
...
void GameBase::onGameOver(){
...
    auto menuShare = MenuItemFont::create(sr->getString(RSTR::share), CC_CALLBACK_1(GameBase::onShare, this));
...
}
...
void GameBase::onShare(Ref* pSender){
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playEffect(SOUND_BTN);
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM==CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID || CC_TARGET_PLATFORM==CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    doShare(this->_mode, this->_best);
#endif /* CC_TARGET_PLATFORM */
}
....
```

* sr->getString(RSTR::share), this is for multiple-language support, it returns the text 'Share' in English environment.

AppDelegate.cpp

```
void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    director->pause();
    director->stopAnimation();
    GameBase *game;
    auto scene = director->getRunningScene();
    if (game = dynamic_cast<GameBase *>(scene->getChildByTag(TAG_GAMESCENE))) {
        game->onSaveProgress();
    }
}

void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() {
    director->resume();
    director->startAnimation(); 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this blinking you are referring to? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Al-mo, My apologizes for not being clear enough. By blink, I mean the menu item changes frequently between selected status and normal status. Take MenuItemFont for example, the text would change between larger size and smaller size.

Comment: I have to see it to understand it, but we faced a similar issue in which the sprites gave a jerky effect(this too off and on like you mentioned), the reason came out to be the switching of our application from background/foreground without pausing the ANIMATIONS while doing it ... may be this is your problem? It's my guess.

Comment: Thank you for comments! I will try to make a video about it. I am not sure the animations you mentioned was doing the trick. But I did not change much in the appDelegate.cpp file and the default action of switch between background/foreground has the code of handling animations. Did you see the jerky effect occasionally or constantly?

Comment: Most of the times(it was during Facebook login, when we pressed the button it gave a jerky effect), following code piece fixed it
>>> applicationDidEnterBackground >>> CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();
======== AND ========   >>> applicationWillEnterForeground >>> CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();

Comment: Thank you! I will try this when I go back home tonight. Sounds like it can solve it although in my case it only happens like 3 out of 10 times.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work for me, so I can still see the blinking item now and then.. Thank you all the same!

Comment: Well now I need to the see the code!

Comment: @Al-mo, Please see the edited code, where I just added the full related code. Thank you!

Comment: May I see the AppDelegate.cpp? Because to me (I don't know what others think of it) this code piece is not causing that issue. It is certainly something related to your Activity going from foreground to background and back.

Comment: Hello AI-mo, thank you for the help and now I have posted the appdelegate code. The only difference between auto-genrated code is that I added pause/resume as you suggested and a save progress on EnterBackground

Comment: I see that you are doing it on Android, try using either of the two pairs(pause/resume And start/stop) IMO, the pause/resume should work. By either of the two I meant ONLY 1 pair at a time. I myself used only pause/resume and the jerky effect on the menu items stopped happening. Do not use both like you have. If even this doesn't work I'm either gonna pull my hair Or gonna ask you the entire code base!

Comment: Ok, I will adopt the suggested way. But I am not sure whether it has to do with the animation when enter/leave background. I have another scene, where other animations stops while only the clicked menuitem sometimes get blinking.. Regardless, I will try it.

Comment: "where other animations stops while only the clicked menuitem sometimes get blinking" >>> exact same issue that we faced.

Comment: I tried to remove the stop/start animation and used only pause/resume instead. Amazingly I have not seen the problem any more! Thank you for the help! Would you please post it as a separate answer and I will accept it. (I cannot accept a comment as answer). Thank you again for the help all the way~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.cpp

Function >>> applicationDidEnterBackground

And in Function >>> applicationWillEnterForeground

I would suggest you use c++ directives to differentiate the code pieces for iOS and Android.

For the Android part use only PAUSE/RESUME pair and for the iOS, use the one you have pasted.

So it would be

```
//applicationDidEnterBackground 
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM==CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    director->pause();
#else
    director->pause();
    director->stopAnimation();
#endif

//applicationWillEnterForeground 
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM==CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    director->resume();
#else
    director->resume();
    director->startAnimation(); 
#endif
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in platform.cpp equivalent

```
    #if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    void onShare() {
         cocos2d::JniMethodInfo t;
        if (cocos2d::JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t
                                                    , NativeActivityClassName
                                                    , "onShare"
                                                    , "()V"))
        {
            t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID);
            t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
        }
    }

    #endif
```

It works fine without blinking share button. Are you calling by some other way?

Comment: can you share the line where you create the menuitem?

Comment: thanks for reply, and here is the code:
auto share = MenuItemFont::create("Share", CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::onShareCallback, this));
 auto menu = Menu::create(share, nullptr); 
As I said, most of the time it works perfect, but if I watch the share button carefully, it sometimes just changes frequently between larger size and smaller size, and only stops this after the share dialog dismiss. It does not bother me much indeed, after all it is not very noticeable and but I just want to know why.